# remove space between toolbar buttons

Tags: iphone, button, toolbar

i am trying to implement segmentedcontroll item since segmentedcontroll does not work what i want. so i have two images and i am adding them into toolbar like this;

> [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, barButtonToday, barButtonPopular,flexibleSpace,nil]];

but always there is space between buttons. how can remove the space? i do not want to space between buttons.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may very well be something that is a drawback to using a UIToolbar as a Segmented Control. What are you trying to do? There might be another way to do what you want.

Comment: i want to be able to click to selected button and deselect all buttons.

Comment: i can not click selected button